# Periodically play short audio, in the background, on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, background-process

I need my iOS app to be able to play a very short sound at regular intervals while my app is in the background. I must support almost any duration/interval time. One example would be a one-second sound, played every 3 seconds for 45 minutes.

I've found an app in the App Store which can do exactly this. (On iOS15). Though from what I've read, this is not possible, outside of creating a 45 minute audio file on the fly, and using background audio to play the clip. (Though not sure Apple wouldn't reject even this.)

Any ideas how this app achieves this? Maybe they're creating an audio file?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this mate? I've come up with a requirement for a charity I work with. We don't need to publish the app on the App Store, but it needs to run on an iPad.

Comment: I ended up generating an audio file, on the fly, as needed. Not the greatest solution, but it works! I didn't find any other way to do it.